# vice versa coding for value and its variables

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2 variables A and B
if A =1 then B should B=2
and if A=2 then B should B=1
Like this, there are 3 pairs `1-2,3-4,5-6`
What's the best way of making a code instead of just if-else

Comment: `if A =1 then B should B=2` `if A=2 then B should B=1` but what is the *logic* behind values of B? For now it looks like you want B to have value of A increased by 1 if A is odd, and decreased by 1 if value of A is even. And why would you want to avoid `if`s?

Comment: `b = ((a-1) ^ 1) + 1;`

Comment: @user3386109 Interesting. That works. I haven’t completely understood how (though I am sure I could analyse my way though it).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use simple addition and subtraction to get the other element of the two `(x, x + 1)`:

```
int a = 1; // the other is 2, sum is 3
int b = 3 - a;  // if a = 2, b = 1

int c = 3; // the other is 4, sum is 7
int d = 7 - c; // if c = 4, d = 3

int m = 5; // the other is 6, sum is 11
int n = 11 - m;
```

Another approach could be using the following logic:

```
if (a % 2 == 1) b = a + 1;
else b = a - 1;
```

So, an array could be used to provide +/- 1:

```java
static int[] signs = {-1, 1};
public static int nextWithArrPositive(int a) {
    return a + signs [a % 2];
}
```

This expression fails to work for negative `a` as in this case `a % 2 == -1` and more advanced logic would be required to calculate the value properly to take into account the negative remainder:

```java
public static int nextWithArr(int a) {
    int sign = (a & 0x80000000) >> 31; //-1 if a < 0, 0 otherwise
    // a >= 0 : 0 - even, 1 - odd;
    // a  < 0 : 1 - even, 0 - odd
    return a + signs[a % 2 - sign];
}
```

However, a simpler expression can be designed:

```java
public static int nextWithMod(int a) {
    return a + a % 2 - (a - 1) % 2;
}
```

Let's compare the results of the three implementations including xor solution `b = ((a - 1) ^ 1) + 1` offered in the comments by user3386109:

```java
public static int nextXor(int a) {
    return ((a - 1) ^ 1) + 1;
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+-----+");
System.out.println("|  a  | arr | mod | xor |");
System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+-----+");
for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.printf("| %2d  | %2d  | %2d  | %2d  |%n", i, nextWithArr(i), nextWithMod(i), nextXor(i));
}
System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+-----+");
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  | arr | mod | xor |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| -6  | -5  | -5  | -7  |
| -5  | -6  | -6  | -4  |
| -4  | -3  | -3  | -5  |
| -3  | -4  | -4  | -2  |
| -2  | -1  | -1  | -3  |
| -1  | -2  | -2  |  0  |
|  0  | -1  |  1  | -1  |
|  1  |  2  |  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  1  |  1  |  1  |
|  3  |  4  |  4  |  4  |
|  4  |  3  |  3  |  3  |
|  5  |  6  |  6  |  6  |
|  6  |  5  |  5  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is a table lookup. In an array for each possible value of `a` I store the corresponding value of `b`:

```
private static final int[] B_PER_A = { -1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5 };
```

Since array indices always start at 0 in Java, we need to put a dummy value at index 0. This value is never used (or should never be, at least).

Let’s try it out:

```
    for (int a = 1; a <= 6; a++) {
        int b = B_PER_A[a];
        System.out.format("a: %d; b: %d.%n", a, b);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> a: 1; b: 2.
> a: 2; b: 1.
> a: 3; b: 4.
> a: 4; b: 3.
> a: 5; b: 6.
> a: 6; b: 5.
> ```

### Generalized to more than 3 pairs

If you need to handle a variable number of pairs, resort to math.

```
public static int calcB(int a) {
    // 0-based index of pair (0 = 1-2, 1 = 3-4, etc.)
    int pairNumber = (a - 1) / 2;
    // a + b for given pair
    int pairSum = 4 * pairNumber + 3;
    int b = pairSum - a;
    return b;
}
```

In each pair the sum is equivalent to 3 modulo 4. I am exploiting this fact in finding the sum for a given pair. When I subtract `a` from that sum, I get `b`. Let’s see that demonstrated  too:

```
    for (int a = 1; a <= 8; a++) {
        int b = calcB(a);
        System.out.format("a: %d; b: %d.%n", a, b);
    }
```

> ```
> a: 1; b: 2.
> a: 2; b: 1.
> a: 3; b: 4.
> a: 4; b: 3.
> a: 5; b: 6.
> a: 6; b: 5.
> a: 7; b: 8.
> a: 8; b: 7.
> ```

The latter solution is more complicated and harder to read. So if you always have got three pairs, no more, no less, I recommend the simpler table lookup presented first.